# setting and accessing props in react functional components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

I am trying to access redux store variable in a react functional components. code below,

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import {
  Redirect,
  Route,
  RouteComponentProps,
  RouteProps
} from "react-router-dom";
import { Wizard } from "../models/wizard";
import { IStoreState } from "../redux/reducers/index";
import { WizardStage } from "../models/enums";
import { PrivateRoute } from "./PrivateRoute";
import { GettingStarted } from "./GettingStarted";

interface IWizardRouteProps extends RouteProps {
  wizard: Wizard;
}

export const _WizardRoute = ({ component, ...rest }: IWizardRouteProps) => {
  if (!component) {
    throw Error("component is undefined");
  }

  const Component = component;

  const render = (props: RouteComponentProps<any>): React.ReactNode => {

    **if (props.wizard.wizardStage===WizardStage.InProgress) {
      return <PrivateRoute {...props} component={Component} />;
    }**

    return (
      <PrivateRoute
        exact
        path="/quote/getting-started"
        component={GettingStarted}
      />
    );
  };

  return <Route {...rest} render={render} />;
};

const mapStateToProps = ({
  wizard
}: IStoreState): {
  wizard: Wizard;
} => {
  return { wizard };
};

export const WizardRoute = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  null
)(_WizardRoute);
```

Not sure what I am missing. I can't seem to access the wizard from store in the code about and getting a compile time error in the if condtion. Getting the following error,

```
Property 'wizard' does not exist on type 'RouteComponentProps<any, StaticContext, any>'.ts(2339)
```

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**

Chris Heald suggestion worked. But now I am getting the following error. Also changed the code to a class component. I am passing in the wizard as props

```
import React from "react";
import { Redirect, Route, RouteProps } from "react-router-dom";
import { Wizard } from "../models/wizard";
import { WizardStage } from "../models/enums";
interface IPrivateWizardRouteProps {
  wizard: Wizard;
}
export class PrivateWizardRoute extends React.Component<
  IPrivateWizardRouteProps & RouteProps
> {
  renderThis = (props: any) => {
    if (this.props.wizard.wizardStage === WizardStage.InProgress) {
      return <React.Component {...props} />;
    } else {
      debugger;
      return (
        <Redirect
          to={{
            pathname: "/quote/getting-started"
          }}
        />
      );
    }
  };
  render() {
    const { path, exact } = this.props;
    console.log(this.props);
    return (
      <Route
        path={path}
        exact={exact}
        render={props => this.renderThis(props)}
      />
    );
  }
}
export default PrivateWizardRoute;
```

[image]

Comment: I think, you should pass wizard as a prop from parent class component. I am using hooks for a while but I remember that you can't  reach store in a functional component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript is complaining that your `props`, defined as a `RouteComponentProps`, doesn't expect a property named `wizard`. If you look at the [type definition](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/eafef8bd049017b3998939de2edbab5d8a96423b/types/mirrorx/index.d.ts#L54-L59) for it, it clearly doesn't!

You should be able to just have your function expect a new interface composed of both `RouteComponentProps` and `IWizardRouteProps`:

```
const render = (props: RouteComponentProps<any> & IWizardRouteProps)
```

As an aside, you should probably be using `useCallback` to define your render function, rather than just defining it in place; otherwise, you'll redefine the function each time the component renders.

Comment: thanksman. That actually worked. I am getting a different error updated the question.

Comment: Returning a bare `React.Component` isn't going to do much for you. Why did you do that? I'd keep the functional style, just wrap your render function in `React.useCallback(..., [Component])` and call it a day.